# Can't get .iso creation tools working in 18.04

Tags: iso

I'm trying to prepare a laptop for return to stock. I have the current copy of dban.iso on-hand.

Startup Disk Creator ignores my selection of dban.

unetbootin launched (as root) throws errors:

```
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x15c
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x3a0000f
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00010
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00010
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00010
```

I'd very grateful for any guidance or if there are other tools to accomplish my task, I'd be grateful to learn of those.

Thank You

Comment: I just use `dd` myself, but `gnome-multi-writer` would be my next choice *(it'll write many at once; so I avoid if I want to write only one but have multiple usb-devices installed*) - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gnome-multi&searchon=names

Comment: Have you looked into [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) / `guidus`?  It tends to be more effective than the really old Startup Disk Creator tool (in fact, this replaced it), and actually works unlike `unetbootin` with installing various ISOs, DBAN included.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.
Please go for this command

```
$sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 unetbootin
```

If it does not work, then first uninstall your current version of unetbootin, then use official unetbootin page to install using ppa instead of deb files. If fails then try opening it from launcher instead of terminal.